# Latest upgrade made io.elementary.contractor.file-roller package "no longer required"

Tags: pantheon-files

This morning my `apt dist-upgrade` routine resulted in one new package - `io.elementary.portals`.

Furthermore, this new upgrade made `io.elementary.contractor.file-roller` package "no longer required". Needless to say that that's not true. Removing this package left me with Files having no right-click menu with archiving options so I had to reinstall it.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Cheers.

Comment: I also noticed this. Maybe related to this pr? https://github.com/elementary/seeds/pull/86 I wonder if they're meaning to move to the flatpak version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is related to elementary moving to Flatpak apps - these will not work with the existing contractor infra-structure because of sandboxing and an alternative solution is being worked on.  However, it seems premature to say contracts are redundant since some apps - in particular Files - are unlikely to ever be Flatpak'd and at the moment continue to work with contracts.  The intention is to have Files use the new methodology as it evolves - we are currently working on a "Send as Email" portal that Files will use.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for your time and effort but I don't understand why to remove something that is useful if the replacement is not ready or even perhaps not on the map yet.

Comment: Probably an oversight. Developers are only human ;-)

Comment: A fix for file-roller flatpak is currently being worked - see https://github.com/elementary/fileroller/pull/12

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy, for this update.